# Shortest distance from point to function scipy

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, points, spline

Given the output of [scipy.interpolate.interp1d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp1d) (function f) and a 2D point (let's say `test_pnt.X` and `test_pnt.Y`) is there a scipy function to calculate the shortest distance from the point `test_pnt` to the function `f`?

Note: `f` is a function that takes in x and returns an interpolated y, i.e. y=f(x)

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
 scipy.lining.norm(x-test_pnt.X, f(x) - test_pnt.Y)
```

to get the actual distance between the point and the function

Comment: what is the little-x in this case? I know you could create a for loop to run over all possible little-x's, but I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way (built into scipy)?

Comment: You might find what you are looking for here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html